# Onde guardar chave privada gerada no WebService?

Tags: web-service, segurança, criptografia

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

> **(e infelizmente não posso mudar nada na infraestrutura, mas posso mudar qualquer coisa em relação ao código da Aplicação e do WebService)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma Intranet com várias bases de dados que só podem ser acessadas por quem está dentro da rede.

Um WebService (na parte superior da imagem) foi criado e colocado nessa rede interna para disponibilizar determinados serviços para aplicações externas específicas.

Uma aplicação externa específica (em Asp.Net MVC na parte inferior da imagem) que consome os serviços disponíveis no WebService, manipula os dados e disponibiliza as informações para os clientes.

Existe uma base de dados (a esquerda na imagem) onde é armazenado todos os dados gerados através da aplicação, mas também é acessível pelo WebService.

Infelizmente, os dados para acessar cada uma das bases de dados da rede interna estão na base de dados da aplicação. Dados extremamente sensíveis!

Como não posso remover os dados sensíveis e criar uma nova base de dados dentro da rede interna para mante-los "seguros", pensei no seguinte processo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após uma solicitação feita pelo cliente na aplicação, um "Token" é gerado e salvo na base de dados da aplicação.

Após salvar o Token, a aplicação faz uma requisição ao WebService enviando o Token. Como o WebService tem acesso a base de dados da aplicação, então fica fácil validar o Token.

Caso tudo esteja certo, então o WebService gera as chaves usando a classe `RSACryptoServiceProvider` e retorna a chave pública, **mantendo também a chave privada em algum lugar (poderia ser a sessão?)**.

Ao receber a chave pública, a aplicação criptografa os dados sensíveis, e também gera as chaves pública e privada do mesmo modo, enviando junto com os dados sensíveis criptografados a chave pública para o WebService.

O WebService recebe os dados e poderá descriptografar tudo com a chave privada armazenada de forma "segura" anteriormente, então busca os dados na rede interna, criptografa tudo com a chave pública que recebeu da aplicação e retorna os dados para ela.

A aplicação pode então descriptografar dos dados com sua chave privada e dar o retorno para o usuário.

As dúvidas são:

> 1. Esta é realmente a forma mais segura de realizar todo o processo tendo em vista todas as limitações e possibilidades citadas?
> 2. Seria apropriado ("seguro") armazenar a chave privada gerada no WebService em uma sessão?